# Como servir um site em múltiplos idiomas no Apache?

Tags: apache, cookies, http-headers, internacionalização

Estou desenvolvendo um site que precisa ser disponibilizado em 3 idiomas (somente conteúdo estático, a ser servido pelo Apache). Gostaria de fazer uso das funcionalidades de detecção de idioma de modo que o usuário já caísse numa versão compatível com as preferências de linguagem do seu *browser*, mas também quero que ele possa escolher um idioma diferente através de links especiais. É possível fazer isso pelo Apache, sem o uso de alguma linguagem *server-side*?

Eu comecei a ler a documentação sobre [*content negotiation*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) e sobre o [`mod_negotiation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html), mas estou bastante perdido, pois os exemplos dados não me parecem claros. O que eu entendi até o momento (por favor me corrijam se eu estiver enganado) foi o seguinte:

- Eu devo criar minhas páginas segundo uma convenção específica, ex.: `index.html.pt`, `index.html.en`, `index.html.ja`;
- Eu devo configurar o `Directory` para habilitar a negociação de conteúdo:

  ```
  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          DirectoryIndex index.html
          AllowOverride None
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
          LanguagePriority en pt ja
          ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
  </Directory>
  ```
- Cada página deve linkar para o nome base, sem especificar o idioma, ex.: `href="index.html"`.

Com isso, pelo que eu entendi o servidor será capaz de escolher uma versão baseado no *header* `Accept-Language` que o *browser* envia. Se isso estiver correto, a primeira parte está ok.

Entretanto, não faço ideia de como poderia através de um link alterar a linguagem corrente da página -  e fazê-lo de modo que ela continuasse a ser a linguagem corrente mesmo após o usuário clicar em outros links. A documentação menciona "técnicas avançadas (como cookies ou URL-paths especiais)", mas não consegui entender do que se tratava, e a documentação linkada não ajudou muito. Existe um meio simples de fazer isso? Dê preferência, sem precisar de JavaScript (mas se não tiver outro jeito, tudo bem).

Comment: Para fazer diretamente no apache não sei, mas também não é preciso necessáriamente javascript, pode definir cookies logo que a página é enviada em linguagem server-side, depende do que prefere, ou seja, por ex: meusite.com/pt (default, caso não hajam cookies) tem um link para meusite.com/en, aí há logo parte do script (server side) que implementa um cookie/sessão para que das proximas vezes seja carregado meusite.com/en em vez de meusite.com/pt

Comment: eu estava reparando como o algoritimo do google funciona quando ele redireciona de google.com para google.com.br ou qualquer outro acho que ele usa como criterio o ip e o Accept-Language do cabecalho da requisicao acho essa seria a melhor forma e colocar uma linguagem por default ate existe uma aplicao do google que converte automaticamente a linguagem do site sem precisar fazer alteracoes nas paginas so nao me lembro o nome

Comment: Vamos esperar alguém esclarecer esta sua dúvida agora. :)

Comment: @drmcarvalho Valeu! Essa já não é mera curiosidade, preciso mesmo disso pra um trabalho que estou fazendo. Nos próximos dias, se não tiver uma resposta eu mesmo vou pesquisar e experimentar algumas opções, e se descobrir algo de útil compartilho aqui com o resto da comunidade.

Answer (score 5):

Segundo a ***W3C*** existe uma certa ambiguidade no ***mod_negotiation*** segue o link [When to use language negotiation](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-when-lang-neg) so para salientar exite tambem exploit [Apache HTTPD mod_negotiation Filename Bruter](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/mod_negotiation_brute)

mas uma outra alternativa para contornar isto seria setar um cookie para cada ***index***

***index.html.en***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ingles</title>
<meta http-equiv="Set-Cookie" content="lang=en; path=/en;>
</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">
<h1>bem vindo ao site do ingles</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

***index.html.pt***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>portuguse</title>
<meta http-equiv="Set-Cookie" content="lang=en; path=/pt;">
</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">
<h1>Bem vindo ao Site do portuga!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

***index.html.jp***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>japones</title>
<meta http-equiv="Set-Cookie" content="lang=en; path=/jp;">
</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">
<h1>bem vindo ao site do japa</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

e criar um diretorio para cada

```
http://mydomain.com/en/
http://mydomain.com/pt/
http://mydomain.com/jp/
```

agora e so adicionar as seguintes linhas ao seu apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+)
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com/%1 [R=302,L]
```

***FONTES:***

[How to use the html tag HTTP-EQUIV "SET-COOKIE"](http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv_set_cookie)

[Using Apache2 Content Negotiation To Serve Different Languages](https://www.howtoforge.com/using-apache2-content-negotiation-to-serve-different-languages)

[Check cookie and redirect with apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021552/check-cookie-and-redirect-with-apache)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Pelo que eu entendi, somente o index teria URLs especiais (tornando fácil mudar a linguagem através de um link), o resto continuaria usando mod_negotiation usando o cookie setado pelo index. Parece viável, vou fazer uns testes pra confirmar. O material citado também parece interessante, vou dar uma lida com mais calma. +1

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro que tudo você deve alterar os nomes dos seus ficheiros para terminar em .html, deve ser to tipo index.pt.html

Depois pode usar o mod_rewrite e o mod_geoip para redirecionar trafego de certos ips por país para as páginas pretendidas.

https://linuxconfig.org/redirect-or-block-traffic-based-on-geographical-location-apache-geoip-mod

Adicionar ao apache no Ubuntu

```
# apt-get install libapache2-mod-geoip
```

Instalar o modulo

```
# apache2ctl -M | grep -E "geoip|rewrite"
geoip_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
```

Restart ao apache

```
# service apache2 restart
```

Depois edit o seu .htaccess e coloque

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(PT|BR)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, o mod_geoip certamente traz um recurso adicional. Pessoalmente, eu prefiro o mod_negotiation mesmo, já que ele leva em consideração a linguagem preferencial do browser (e não somente a localização física do usuário).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Certo, mas pense que muita gente usa browsers em Inglês mesmo estando no Br ou em Pt.

Comment: É possível (aliás, eu próprio rsrs!), mas seja qual for a estratégia adotada, terão falsos positivos e falsos negativos. Eu *suspeito* que usar o negotiation como principal e o geoip como *fallback* acertaria com mais frequência do que o contrário. Mas posso estar enganado...

Comment: Se der para fazer o && então é perfeito. Mas isso já eu desconheço. Se não der. Pode fazer tipo passos uma folder inicial filtra um caso depois redireciona para outra pasta e filtra pelo outro. Mas isso so eu a teorizar. Não se é possivel